# How to write, compile and run C# for free (in Windows)

Tags: c#, deployment, ide

Is it possible to use C# for free? Which tools would you use?

1. For fun/studying: I'm pretty sure you can, but still, the tools question remains.
2. For programs you wish to sell?

The tools I'm looking for:

1. IDE (as complete as possible: debugging, refactoring, libraries, IntelliSense etc.) - also, if it's not included in the IDE, compiler.
2. Unit Testing,
3. Documenting (extracting comments as with JavaDoc),
4. Deploying.

Other suggestions for nice free tools are also welcome.

Note that IMO, Visual Studio Express is NOT offering all these tools.

Comment: What doesn't C# Express provide that you want?

Comment: serious deploying, unit testing, documenting if i am correct

Comment: Use Visual Studio 2015 Community, a free edition of VS with all the features of Professional edition https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IDEs:

- [Visual Studio 2017 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/). It has a subset of Professional Edition's features, but all that you have mentioned. You may want to [Compare Visual Studio 2017 Editions](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/). High school and university students are eligible for free licence of VS Professional from [Dreamspark](http://www.dreamspark.com).
- Sharp Develop
- [Mono Develop](http://monodevelop.com/)

standalone compiler:

- csc.exe, vbc.exe and msbuild.exe are a part of .NET Framework. Windows SDK tools is also free. Or you can use compiler from [Mono project](http://mono-project.com/).

---

Unit Testing:

- NUnit, mbUnit, xUnit and many, many others.

Documenting: (extracting comments JavaDoc-style)

- [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) - not for Express Edition

Deploying:

- [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/), [Cruse Control .NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/)

Comment: GhostDoc creates comments, it doesn't extract them. Sandcastle can extract doc comments.

Comment: An alternative to Sandcastle is DocN.

Answer (score 9):

While OP says:

> Visual Studio Express is NOT offering all this tools as claimed!
>
> > What doesn't C# Express provide that you want?
>
> serious deploying, unit testing, documenting

Yet, IMO you *can* do that with Visual Studio Express.

#### Deployment

Visual Studio Deployment projects are certainly missing from Visual Studio Express, but frankly that's not much of an omission. The whole feature is half baked, good enough to tick off a feature list, good enough for toy deployments but, arguably, not really up to the rigors of the real world.

[Windows Installer XML](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (WiX) is an open source toolkit from Microsoft for creating installers. The installer for Microsoft Office 2007 was [reportedly](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/) built with WiX, so it's reasonable to believe that it can handle any smaller case.

Another installation tool is the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), perhaps easier to understand than WiX, but also not using with the MSI technology built into Windows and therefore harder to manage in the Enterprise case.

#### Unit Testing

The Microsoft testing framework is [MSTest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSTest), and while it's up to the task, it's not the leader of the pack. In fact, if you google around for reactions to MSTest, you'll find many who think it a ripoff of [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/).

There was a time that you could integrate any of the test tools into Visual Studio Express, using [Test Driven.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/), though that no longer works.

What *does* work is to use the external runner programs for your unit testing tool - all of the major unit testing frameworks come with them. When using VS Express myself, I tend to have the test runner hanging around in the background; rerunning tests then just involves a task switch.

NUnit is the grandaddy of the .NET testing frameworks, and it works very well. There are others around though, such as [mbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) and [xUnit](http://www.codeplex.com/xunit).

#### Documentation

No version of Visual Studio has a good story for documentation. In fact, they all have the *same story* - a compiler switch to generate XML files based on the documentation comments.

To convert those XML files into real documentation, you need other tools. [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) used to be the standard, but that project is unfortunately now dead ([quite a sad tale](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/archive/2006/07/26/NDoc-2.0-_2D00_-R.I.P.aspx)). [Sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/) (another Microsoft Open Source project) is likely to become the new gold standard, but the tool isn't yet as mature and easy to use as we would like. [DocU](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/03/19/introducing-docu-simple-doc-gen-for-net/) is a new release in this field, might be worth followup.

#### Conclusions

As you can see, there are good ways to achieve the goals you want, even using Visual Studio Express. In fact, there are only two things you'll gain from moving up to a paid version of Visual Studio.

1. You'll get MSTest, if you want it.
2. You'll be able install extensions/plugins like TestDriven.NET and Resharper.

For someone getting started, I don't think the value proposition is there. Start with the free tools and spend money when you have enough experience to spend it well.

Comment: Tx Bevan, I think this post is very  helpful!  I voted you up for it,tx.

Answer (score 5):

1. IDE (as complete as possible, debugging, refactoring, libraries, intellisense, ...)
    => [Sharpdevelop (#develop)](http://sharpdevelop.net/) an Open Source IDE for .Net with support for multiple languages.
2. If not in IDE, compiler
    
        => As mentioned by Jozef
3. Unit Testing
    => Sharpdevelop, NUnit integrated inside
4. Documenting (extracting comments eg, cf javadoc)
    => Sharpdevelop, [SandCastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle) and [SHFB](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB) integrated
5. Deploying
    => Sharpdevelop, [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) integrated.

Check out all the features for Shardevelop at [SharpDevelop Features](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx)

Its free to create programs and sell. For fun you can develop some more features inside it :)

Comment: I have checked now, and voted you up, as well as other very useful answers here
Tx all

Comment: Gonna give a try into ic#dev ide

Answer (score 4):

You can download Visual Studio Express. It includes all that you are asking for. Here is the linky :)

Good luck!

http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/

Comment: It doesn't include unit-test and document generator , also doesn''t have any tools for deployment.

Comment: mm, If think it's a pitty your info seems to be wrong...
Why you are claiming that it has unit-testing and doc generator? Or is Yossi mistaking here?

Comment: Nah, I'm mistaken. I'm not too familiar with Visual Studio Express. I occasionally use Visual Studio Standard, but mostly I'm a UNIX programmer. I was under false impressions. You guys are correct :)

Comment: haha, kudo's, but you still got the points though :-) but you're welcome to it

Comment: As to deployment, the Express versions use the ClickOnce deployment method.  I think that is the only one available.

Comment: Last time I checked, VS Express did not let me change the Build Target(I am not sure if it was the Framework or the Processor, it's been a while).

Answer (score 4):

1. Visual C# express edition
2. Visual C# express edition
3. Nunit
4. SandCastle
5. Don't know , I'll let someone else answer that.

Comment: Why using NDoc and NUnit if VS express already has that?
Or is the opinion higher up (hahuang65) incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/), (or Visual C# 2008 Express, if you don't want to use other languages) is a good choice. It's free.

Non-Microsoft, try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

Edit: if you are a student, and your university is MSDN AA certificated, you can get Visual Studio 2008 Professional for free. Yes, free.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using AA right now, but not forever, hence my question

Comment: Even if your university isn't AA certificated, you can get access through DreamSpark, which only requires an ISIC (international student identification card).

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Visual C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) for your IDE and compiler, [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net) for your documentation, [MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) or [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) for unit testing, and I believe C# Express will handle deployment as well.

Comment: Tx man, (fyi : I'm reading comparison right now, express has indeed a kind of deployment (clickonce) but no MSI)

Comment: In that case, check out Inno (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or Nullsoft's NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/

https://www.dreamspark.com/Products/ProductList.aspx (if you're a student:)

Comment: tx, if you're a student, also check out Vimvq1987, that's the option I'm using right now

Answer (score 1):

Also look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) for deploying - this allows you to create MSI files.